# PHP Regex allow spaces but fail if they are on there own or after a word

Tags: regex

Not wanting to end up with a chameleon question I have started a new one,  I am trying to use php regex to match the following...

- Only allow alphanumeric characters
- Have at least 2 characters
- Does not consist of only numbers

I have this regex so far http://regex101.com/r/lL3uT4....

```
^(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,}$
```

This is working but the following data still validates when i want it to fail...

```
47 (note the space after 47)
   (two spaces next to each other)
```

I understand it is to do with spaces but I still need the following to validate...

```
47 International
3 apple
```

I think what I am trying to do is allow spaces but fail them if the string consists entirely of spaces or if there is a space but then no character afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?! )(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB1hZ5)

Comment: Thanks once again, it's good comparing the two answers so I can see whats changed.  Much appreciated